# Eclipse Spell Check Platform Dictionary

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How is it possible to install a dictionary for **spell check** in eclipse (i'm using Spring Tools Suite) ?

I saw option in *Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text editors -> Spelling*

I don't want add an user dictionary, but a platform dictionary (only for spell check, i want keep user interface in english).

Thank you

Comment: I found this link where to download languages packs
but i don't know which one i must download
 http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/L-3.2_Language_Packs-200607121700/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tt the end i downloaded a italian dictionary made from a word list for my language 
and configured here

*Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text editors->Spelling->User defined dictionary*

[Italian eclipse dictionary](http://www.mediafire.com/?mgyjnnjfir4) (link provided in "shinichi" answer)

[Source forum (italian)](http://www.ioprogrammo.it/index.php?topic=18550.0)